# Solving Fraction exponential modula arithmetic

Tags: cryptography, brute-force, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

Hi guys I am trying to solve a fraction exponential modula arithmetic, but dont seem to figure out how to do so. An example is x is conquerent with 8^1/3 mod 55. How can I solve this.

Comment: this is small, you can search for it. 2

Comment: I have searched for it but yet to see a suitable explanation

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/673418/cube-roots-modulo-p

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about programming but is a math assignment.

Comment: As per @kelalaka link, you solve for the cube root mod 5 and mod 11 separately, then combine these results using the Chinese Remainder Theorem to get the answer mod (5*11)=55.